# Magento2.4.2 multi website setup not working

Tags: magento2, htaccess, magento2.4.2, litespeed

I have upgraded the Magento version from 2.3.3 to M2.4.2 now the main `example.com` working fine and `example.com/wholesale` | `example.com/retail` not working. I have copied `.htaccess` from pub to these subfolders but it's not working. following errors are throwing:

```
Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Here is index.php

```
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'wholesale'; 
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento 2.4.2 now enforces the best practice of serving all content from *magento_root/pub*.

Most sites won't notice this change because of the rewrites in the 2.4.2 version of `magento_root/.htaccess`

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/640cad53009b291334234ccd61ab79f256b43da2

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

These rewrites will have no effect on stores served from sub folders **which will now be broken**.

The simplest way to load one or more stores via url sub folders is to create the sub folder in `magento_root/pub` and symlink to the static pub folders/files.

For example

https://shop.com/wholesale/

```
mkdir magento_root/pub/wholesale
cd magento_root/pub/wholesale
ln -s ../media media
ln -s ../static static
ln -s ../../pub pub
ln -s ../.htaccess .htaccess
ln -s ../health_check.php health_check.php
```

`magento_root/pub/wholesale/index.php`

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'wholesale'; 
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: Do I need to edit this file magento_root/pub/shop01/index.php or magento_root/pub/index.php?

Comment: Have updated the answer to match your requirements better,

Answer (score 1):

@paj's solution must be completed with this step to allow app/bootstrap.php to be pointed correctly:

> magento_root/pub/wholesale/index.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
```

@Balaji Kaliyaperumal that symlink isn't helpful, but thanks for pointing out the path.

Answer (score 1):

**Multi-Store Setup (Apache)**

> **Create a virtual host for your main example.com**

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/{virtualname}com.conf
```

> **Here {virtualname} is the file name you can add any name as you need. Our hostname is an example then we used that name.**

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/examplecom.conf
```

> **After creating please open that file. And add below code content(must be open with root user):**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/pub

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/example/pub>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

> **Now we are enabling this site file using the below command:**

```
sudo a2ensite examplecom.conf
```

> **Add your new hostname into the system hosts file using the below command:**

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

> **After opening the file please add this:**

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

> **When you enable any site file or add a new host then you must restart the service using the below command:**

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2

Ubuntu: service apache2 restart

CentOS: service httpd restart
```

**After the above process http://example.com/ URL is working. Now we set up a multi-store URL. as per your requirement multi-store folders are created into /var/www/html/example/pub directory. Here we are creating two folders wholesale and retail.**

```
cd /var/www/html/example/pub

mkdir wholesale

mkdir retail
```

**After making the directory, we need to copy the index.php and .htaccess file from /var/www/html/example/pub directory and place it into your newly created folders (wholesale and retail).**

**index.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = array_replace_recursive(
    $params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] ?? [],
    [
        DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
        DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
        DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
        DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
    ]
);
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

> **Do not copy the root .htaccess file. Copy pub directory .htaccess file. And add the below line:**

```
# SET MULTI-STORE CODE NAME

SetEnvIf Host .*example.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=YourWebsiteCode
SetEnvIf Host .*example.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

[image]

**Get your website code. Go Stores -> Configuration -> Settings -> All Stores**

**Now you must restart the service using the below command:**

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2

Ubuntu: service apache2 restart

CentOS: service httpd restart
```

***Note: You must be added the URL in your Magento core_config_data table.***

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/wholesale/
http://example.com/retail/
```

Comment: For disable site use this command : sudo a2dissite {virtual name}com.conf

Answer (score 0):

I think "`ln -s ../../app app`" is missing in symlink. Thanks

mkdir magento_root/pub/wholesale
cd magento_root/pub/wholesale
ln -s ../media media
ln -s ../static static
ln -s ../../pub pub
ln -s ../../app app
ln -s ../.htaccess .htaccess
ln -s ../health_check.php health_check.php