# Magento 2.3.6-p1 upgrade to 2.4.2 - 404 error on both front end and backend

Tags: 404, magento2.4.2, http-error-404

I recently upgraded one Magento installation on my local from 2.3.6-p1 to 2.4.2, and then I started getting 404 error for all pages on front end and backend, below are the technical details of server, and few tries I already made:

values set in httpd.conf (as I run multiple websites so I place them in subdirectory of /var/www/html)

```
Listen 192.168.1.119:80
Timeout 600
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all      
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

root .htacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

> Note: I added ifmodule statement here to confirm that mod rewrite is
> installed and working.

I have cleared all cache and generated folders using the command below:

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/composer_home generated/
```

and then recompiled and deployed, but not working for me, can anyone help me for the same.

Comment: this solution may be of interest to you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/333595/7863

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"` to `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/pub"` and reload apache.**

Please read more details in this thread [frontend and admin not working magento 2.4.2 upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332400/frontend-and-admin-not-working-magento-2-4-2-upgrade) where I explained why this is needed.

Also, there is an answer there from @iphigenie https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/332405/35330 that attempts to solve the problem of using subfolders for running Magento.

Comment: I am running multiple website under /var/ww/html using sub directories like mydir1, mydir2 and even if I change document root to pub, the path /var/www/html/pub doesn't exist, as the pub folder is inside my subdirectory and its present in each magento installation I have.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out, maybe it helps

Comment: Sorrry for very much delayed response, but finally configured Apache httpd.conf to have pub as root directory for my virtual host entry for the particular website.

Answer (score 0):

It seems now Magento will only load from pub folder. By default it will not be possible to load it from the root of Magento.

***So the best solution for this is to create a virtual host and point it to pub directory.***

**Alternative**

Meanwhile, as an alternative to run this on local machine I tried something else that seems to be working fine with the default setup. Like earlier we were using the `base_url` as `http://127.0.0.1/magento`. So instead of this now we need to use `http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub` as the `base_url`. Secure and Unsecure URL needs to be setup on the basis of this.

Setting this up will avoid the issue of 404 page coming.

Note: Verified this with the default Magento only. Not sure for the projects having much complex functionalities. But you can give this a try.

**We have another option without adding /pub follow below steps**

**1.** Copy .httaccess file from pub folder and override it to root .htaccess file

**2.** Upload pub/index.php file to root magento directory

**3.** Add below code in app/etc/env.php file

```
'system' => [
    'default' => [
        'web' => [
            'unsecure' => [
                'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
            ],
            'secure' => [
                'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```